# Cakephp 3.7.x How to retrieve user data? using Authentication component

Tags: authentication, cakephp, cakephp-3.7

I am using cakephp 3.7.2 with Authentication component

```
$user = $this->Authentication->getIdentity();
```

prints:

```
object(Authentication\Identity) {

'config' => [
    'fieldMap' => [
        'id' => 'id'
    ]
],
'data' => object(App\Model\Entity\User) {

    'id' => (int) 1,
    'email' => 'aa.aaa@gmail.com',
    ...
 }
}
```

I have tried `$user->data` but it doesn't work.

How to print user data?

[Authentication Component](https://github.com/cakephp/authentication)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I have figured it out.

In User Entity class

Add `use Authentication\IdentityInterface;`

and then  implement the IdentityInterface.

```
class User extends Entity implements IdentityInterface
{

blablabla...
yale yale yale ...
```

Now you can print:

```
 $user = $this->Authentication->getIdentity();   
 debug($user->id);
```

Answer (score 0):

As per Authentication component documentation

> The identity object is returned by the service and made available in
>   the request. The object provides a method getIdentifier() that can be
>   called to get the id of the current log in identity.

You can use this accordingly as below to get the user data:

```
 // Service
   $identity =  $authenticationService
        ->getIdentity()
        ->getIdentifier()

    // Component
    $identity = $this->Authentication
        ->getIdentity()
        ->getIdentifier();

    // Request
   $identity = $this->request
        ->getAttribute('identity')
        ->getIdentifier();
```

> The identity object provides ArrayAccess but as well a get() method to
>   access data. It is strongly recommended to use the get() method over
>   array access because the get method is aware of the field mapping.

For eg. to access email and username from the identity you can use the below code.

```
 $identity->get('email'); // to access email 
    $identity->get('username'); // to access username
```

Reference link: [Authentication -> Docs -> Identity Object](https://github.com/cakephp/authentication/blob/master/docs/Identity-Object.md)

Hope this will help.

Comment: In order to get that you will have to do this `$identity = new Identity($data, [
        'fieldMap' => [
            'id' => 'uid',
            'username' => 'first_name'
        ]
    ]);` and then `$identity->get('email');` Otherwise you have to make you custom IdentityInterface.

Answer (score 0):

I´m using AuthComponent in CakePHP 4.xxx.

I can get User data i.e. in a view with

```
$user = $this->getRequest()->getAttribute('identity');
```

I found the Information on: http://gotchahosting.com/blog/category/cakephp/4002624

Maybe it helps someone who is looking for information about this in CakePHP4